# Unable to play Battlefield 3 because of an update but game is completely up to date

Tags: battlefield-3, origin

I'm trying to play BF3 but it won't let me. Whenever I click play it says to update the game, but when I click on update it just brings me back to my Origin application with all my installed games. Nothing shows it needs updating and it all says it is completely up to date. What do I need to do?

Comment: Try reinstalling the game. Sometimes that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bad install of the update, you could try rolling back and then installing the update again, or i would just uninstall the game then reinstall via Origin.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to reinstall the game, but that looks like the easiest option. Just a pain waiting for it to download/install.

Comment: I ended up having to uninstall Origin, BF3 and deleting all instances of Origin/BF3 from any folders that were left on my PC then reinstalled. Works like a charm now, just wish I didn't have to go through all of that.

Comment: That Origin for you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing the game by right clicking on it and choosing 'Repair'.